# Angular JS form with select, checkbox and radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am newbie to angular JS. I had created a simple form with select, checkbox and radio button. I am not clear how the values are binding for these fields in angular. How can i minimize my HTML code and specify the value inside my controller. i want the result of each value to be added and displayed as total when i click on calculate button. My form is as follows.

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="totalController">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="calculate()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Select Model:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option value="40000">Moto turbo</option>
          <option value="20000">Moto X</option>
          <option value="10000">Moto G</option>
          <option value="5000">Moto E</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="color" class="color">Select Color:</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="400">
          Black </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="300">
          Red </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="300">
          White </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="200">
          Yellow </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="250">
    Blue </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Select Panel:</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" value="200">
          Set of 1 Panel</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" value="400">
          Set of 2 Panel</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" value="600">
          Set of 3 Panel</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
      <div role="alert" class="alert alert-success" ng-show="showTotal">   Total is : </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 <!--container--> 
 </body>
```

Controller

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('totalController',["$scope",function($scope){
      $scope.showTotal = false;
      $scope.calculate = (function(){
         $scope.showTotal = true;
          });
     }]);
```

My aim is to understand the value binding for select, checkbox and radio button.

Comment: for the select, use ng-options, for the others, use ng-repeat

Comment: Study some form tutorials and get familiar with the angular docs. Use `ng-model` to bind user input to data model

Answer (score 1):

For the dropdown part, try this code

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <form>
        <select ng-model="myForm.car"
                ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in myForm.options">
        </select>
    </form>

    <div>
        {{myForm.car}}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
        .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
            $scope.myForm = {};
            $scope.myForm.car  = "nissan";

            $scope.myForm.options = [
              { id : "nissan", name: "Nissan" }
             ,{ id : "toyota", name: "Toyota" }
             ,{ id : "fiat"  , name: "Fiat" }
             ];

        } );
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a specific way to do it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WHmg6hShcfUF4FK1ajDk?p=preview

Generally, in order to access the form elements in your controller, you need to use `ng-model`. I would recommend looking at the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input